# Problem with session based login after moving relevant files to site root

Tags: php, session, migration

I have a site which I have been testing in a sub-folder of my client's site-root.
I had no log in problems during testing, but then I moved the new site files from a sub-directory to the main site root, and now I'm losing my logged in state after almost every page refresh in secure areas.

I am running a $_session based login system that refreshes the session id on every page load, with a comparison value stored in the MySQL database.

Does anyone have suggestions for what could be causing this problem?

Comment: DEBUUUUUUUG it! Debug it first, and only then both ask and **answer**!

Answer (score 1):

krico was right in suggesting that the cookie path may be the cause (but the solution proposed seems a bit daft) however you've said that is not the case.

Check to see **exactly** what cookies (name, path, expiry, flags) are being set and returned by using iehttpheaders (MSIE) LiveHeaders (Firefox) or using a network sniffer like wireshark. Then ask the question again providing details of what you found out.

C.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are usually path relevant.  Your previous sub-directory based site was probably setting the cookie (that binds the browser to the user) only for that sub-directory.

A way to fix it is to put a redirection page on the old subdir that adds a cookie to '/' and then redirects to new site on root.

Comment: Not sure I follow. That sub-directory will not exist in the final deployment.

Comment: A cookie in a browser is usualy set for a specific path, so that for example the pages under /web-app-one cannot read the cookies from /web-app-two.

Comment: session.cookie_path is set to / in phpinfo. That sounds right since all the security stuff in handled in one folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you change session id you will loose all data stored in previous session. You must set session name after every session start command

```
<?php
session_name('AnySessName');
?>
```

or use other mechanism to store your variables cross sessions.

Comment: Sorry, I mean a value called $_session['id']. Does this still apply?

Comment: ok. You can write
`<?php Echo $_COOKIE['UserSess']; ?>`
on your page.
Is it changed after reloading page?
Browser is storing session identificator in cookies

Comment: that is not returning anything!

Comment: ok. and if write <?php error_reporting(15);?> before session start wil it returns any errors? looks like seeion not started at all. or lost session. are other variables from session seen?

Comment: sorry. You must call session_name BEFORE you start session)))
I think that you have a new session every time reloaded page.
put <?php Echo session_name(); ?> and refresh several times. Is that value chenged?

Comment: Now I'm seeing UserSess echoed.

Comment: Is it new every time or staying the same?
Now write instead $_COOKIE['UserSess']; $_SESSION['id'];
is it changed? if yes - check changing or placing conditions in your code.

Comment: sorry for my english)))
now we check if SESSION var reachable. What error it returns?

Comment: echoing $_COOKIE['UserSess']; or $_SESSION['id']; returns nothing!

Comment: seems session not reachable or started.